# Can't install OS X on MacBook Pro after installing Windows 8

Tags: macos, bootcamp, install

So my hard drive stopped working, water damage I think. 
I bought myself a new ssd and straightaway put Windows on it as I use it for work.

This was a few months ago I'm now stuck as I can't figure out how to install OS X whilst Windows is its main OS.

If anyone has a solution that doesn't involve me wiping my ssd I'd be very happy.

Answer (score 1):

Boot with ⌘R, use Disk Utility to partition the disk, then use the OS X Utilities to reinstall OS X, selecting the new partition as the destination.

Answer (score -2):

Use a virtual machine. You can run mac on windows. But it is a hacked version of OS X so i don't think you would want it because it is not the legal copy.